# using jquery attr to set css this attr value?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to add any element with attr **ae-mw** css with **his attr value** ? in one line

```
<div class="ahmed" ae-mw="200px" >ahmed</div><script>$(document).ready(function () {$('body *[ae-mw]').css("max-width", $(this).attr("ae-mw"));});</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for using `this`

First get the element, I selected the element using the classname, and then get the attribute using jquery's `.attr()` function

Here you got it in one line

```
<div class="ahmed" ae-mw="200px" >ahmed</div><script>$(document).ready(function () {$('.ahmed').css("max-width", $('.ahmed').attr('ae-mw'));});</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer  .. but what if dont have class or id ?? so i need it with attr >

Comment: Then replace `$('.ahmed')` with `$('[ae-mw]')` remember to do it both places

Comment: Great !! .. but it's put the same value on all ( can i have more than one )

    <div class="ahmed" ae-mw="200px" >ahmed</div>
    <div class="ahmed" ae-mw="300px" >ahmed</div>
    <div class="ahmed" ae-mw="500px" >ahmed</div>
    <script>$(document).ready(function () {$('[ae-mw]').css("max-width", $('[ae-mw]').attr('ae-mw'));});</script>

    <script>

Comment: Then copy this javascript into the script `$(document).ready(function(){
  const elements = $('[ae-mw]');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const maxWidth = elements[i].getAttribute('ae-mw');
    elements[i].style.maxWidth = maxWidth;
   }
});`